# Initializing and adding arrays to a multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I want to define and initialize arrays in **php** and then add them to a multi-dimensional array. I have searched alot through the net but find solutions in which initialization of sub-arrays is done within the multidimensional array body. I have 12 arrays and each having 90 values. The data is numeric.

I have selected data of product categories from the database and saved them in separate arrays like this:

```
    $books_cds = array();

    $books_cds[] = $row1['books_cds'];

    $mobile_computer = array();

    $mobile_computer[] = $row2['mobile_computer'];

    $clothes_shoes = array();

    $clothes_shoes[] = $row3['clothes_shoes'];
```

> Now I want to save $books_cds[ ], $ mobile_computer[ ] and $clothes_shoes[ ] in a multidimensional array. And then want to access $books_cds[ ] from multidimensional array through its index in that array. How should I do this?

Comment: Post some code you tried. That would help us understand your question better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$multi[] = $books_cds;
$multi[] = $mobile_computer;
$multi[] = $clothes_shoes;
var_dump($multi);
```

var_dump is a very useful function :)

Or you can do this as well:

```
$multi['books_cds'] = $books_cds;
$multi['mobile_computer'] = $mobile_computer;
$multi['clothes_shoes'] = $clothes_shoes;
```

And you can access the values like this:

```
print $multi['books_cds'][0];
```

But again, use var_dump to see exactly what is going on.

Comment: How can I access complete array books_cds from $multi array?

Comment: The complete books_cds array is: $multi['books_cds']

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want to achieve. You can add a sub-array to another array like this:

```
$main = array();
$sub = array(1, 2, 3, 6);
$main[] = $sub; // OR: $main[0] = $sub;
```

I this what you mean? Or maybe you can supply more information (like a code example).

Comment: I have 12 arrays like this:  $grocery[];$movie_tickets[]; and so on. I want to save them in a multidimensional array. and access complete subarray through its index.